# How to use PHP Mailer and keep my SMTP credentials secure?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, phpmailer

I apologize if I sound like a noob, but I am.. Learning!

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how my credentials would be kept safe? using PHPMailer for a contact form on my website.

In the SMTP Parameters, you are supposed to type in your credentials quite explicitly:

```
/* SMTP parameters. */

   /* Tells PHPMailer to use SMTP. */
   $mail->isSMTP();

   /* SMTP server address. */
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';

   /* Use SMTP authentication. */
   $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

   /* Set the encryption system. */
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

   /* SMTP authentication username. */
   $mail->Username = 'smtp@example.com';

   /* SMTP authentication password. */
   $mail->Password = 'password';

   /* Set the SMTP port. */
   $mail->Port = 587;
```

How is it possible for these credentials to not be easily get stolen? Is there a way to hide them more securely and somehow pass them through? Where is the best place to put these PHPMailer files on my server? Should they be in the 'public_HTML' folder where my website's files are?

Thanks!

Comment: safe is relative, stolen by whom?

Comment: Same from people accessing my site? Viewing my source code using like dev tools on a browser for example? granted, if someone FTPs into my server its toast either way....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, PHP output is read by an interpreter on the server and output (generally) as HTML.

The webserver configuration can control what files are served by the web server and available to view / download. In a typical web server configuration, php files are only interpreted and source is not available over http. You should check this with your hosting provider.

However,  you might be interested in the $_ENV global variable, when used, values can be set out of context (not directly in script). This is mostly useful to avoid storing sensitive information in version control systems like git

Comment: I can't believe everyone is down voting my post. thanks for providing back an actually useful answer

Comment: I am not sure why they are down voting your post either. It may be, because your question is very broad. You also have several questions in one question. I would consider asking questions separately. Don't worry, I understand. Everyone has to start somewhere. If you are concerned about the security of your web application, do yourself a favor and read, and eventually fully understand https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_2017_Project.